# How to : Invoke API Gateway endpoint with IAM authorization using golang client

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

It seems pretty straight forward, but I am not able to figure out yet.

In the code such as below -

```
resp, err := http.Get("API Gateway endpoint url goes here")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

I am not sure how I tell http.get to use AWS auth. aws cli is configured the access key and secret on the host. So I do not want to again mention in the code.

Some posts mentioned about signing request. But I am not sure if that's the right way. In light of the AWS SDK in golang, this feels bit low level stuff.
I would expect either

1. There must a way in AWS SDK that encapsulates signing HTTP request etc. and does the job
2. There must be a way to do this using http inbuild package by "somehow" attaching aws creds.

Any help is much, much appreciated!

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Do you need to add certain http headers (e.g. `x-api-key`)?

Comment: It would probably help potential responders to know what the context is. E.g., is it for a certain API-Gateway endpoint?  Does that API-Gateway project have certain requirements?
Is this to trigger an AWS lambda function? ...

Comment: @jcfollower let's just say it's a simple call to an endpoint that's created using api gateway. That is a pretty common use case. A golang client wants to call this api endpoint from a server where aws cli has configured access key and secret.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I doubt that the aws cli access key and secret have anything to do with making a GET request on an API-Gateway endpoint.

Does the owner of the API-Gateway endpoint have any documentation for how to access it?

Comment: Have you read through this?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html

Comment: @jcfollower - yes.

Comment: Does this SO answer help?

[edited -- new link]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487025/856070

Comment: No. I have mentioned in the question about the same.

Comment: `it's a simple call to an endpoint that's created using api gateway.` - what's the authentication method on the API gateway you set up?

Comment: `There must a way in AWS SDK that encapsulates signing HTTP request etc. and does the job` - there is, the answer linked above refers to `signer.SignHTTP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some posts mentioned signing requests. But I am not sure if that's the right way

Yes, IAM Auth requires request signing (see docs [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/#Security_and_Authorization)).  The current method is [Signature v4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). Api Gateway accepts a request if it has the [expected headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_elements.html).  "Signing" is the process of adding the right headers:

```bash
# signature is derived from your secret key and the request contents.
--header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIASIAXTWO8D5GSN4CS/20220712/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=f2d8478ceff83d5cd0696502cb58a8331304846d11367d74608295c7acbfba0c'
# date prevents third parties from intercepting your request and resubmitting it later
--header 'X-Amz-Date: 20220712T124302Z'
```

> There must a way in AWS SDK that encapsulates signing HTTP request etc. and does the job

For several languages (JS, Java, etc. but not Go), the [get-sdk](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/apigateway/get-sdk.html) command can generate a [SDK client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html) for your Rest API that, among other conveniences, wraps the signature process: `client.privateGet(params, body, additionalParams)`.

> There must be a way to do this using http inbuild package by "somehow" attaching aws creds

Using the plain-old SDKs it's a bit more work to add the headers, easily wrappable in a resusable type:

```golang
ctx := context.TODO()

// define the request
endpoint := "https://cbi3vltq21.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
u, _ := url.ParseRequestURI(endpoint)
u.Path = "prod/private"
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", u.String(), nil)

// get the credentials from the local config files
cfg, _ := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx,
  config.WithRegion("us-east-1"),
  config.WithSharedConfigProfile("my-profile"))
creds, _ :=  cfg.Credentials.Retrieve(ctx) 

// hash the request body - hex value used in the signature
hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte("")) // if the request has no body, use the empty string
hexHash := fmt.Sprintf("%x", hash)

// add the Authorization and X-Amz-Date headers to the request
signer := v4.NewSigner()
_ = signer.SignHTTP(ctx, creds, req, hexHash, "execute-api", cfg.Region, time.Now())

// execute the request
client := &http.Client{}
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
```

H/T to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487025/1103511).